# Problem with remove-if and cl-remove-if

Tags: cl-lib, cl

I have a very useful bit of code in my .emacs file which closes all buffers except the current one, and scratch and TeX_snippets.org buffers:

```lisp
(defun my/kill-all-buffers-except-toolbox ()
  "Kill all buffers except current one and toolkit (*Messages*, *scratch*).
Close other windows."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (remove-if
                      (lambda (x)
                        (or (eq x (current-buffer))
                            (member (buffer-name x)
                                    '("*scratch*" "TeX_snippets.org"))))
                      (buffer-list)))
  (delete-other-windows))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c m") 'my/kill-all-buffers-except-toolbox)
```

On upgrading to emacs 28.2 (9) on Mac OS X, it appears that `cl` (from which `remove-if` comes) is deprecated. Apparently the functions have been renamed to, in this case, `cl-remove-if` and is in `cl-lib`. I made this change in the .emacs file:

```lisp
(defun my/kill-all-buffers-except-toolbox ()
  "Kill all buffers except current one and toolkit (*Messages*, *scratch*).
Close other windows."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (cl-remove-if
                      (lambda (x)
                        (or (eq x (current-buffer))
                            (member (buffer-name x)
                                    '("*scratch*" "TeX_snippets.org"))))
                      (buffer-list)))
  (delete-other-windows))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c m") 'my/kill-all-buffers-except-toolbox)
```

but nothing happens when I hit `C-c m`. I have seen it suggested the `(require 'cl-lib)` is required -- adding that to .emacs makes no change. What am I missing/doing wrong? This is an extremely useful function for me.

Comment: Try `(require 'cl-seq)` instead: that is where `cl-remove-if` is defined.

Comment: Tried it -- no change, still does not work. Thanks for suggestion, though...

Comment: If you already required `cl-lib` then `cl-remove-if` should work. Have you tried evaluating the `cl-remove-if` expression separately (put your cursor after the closing parenthesis of that expression and press `C-x C-e`)?

Comment: Odd. `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable cl-remove-if)`

Comment: OP: @dalanicolai means evaluate the whole `cl-remove-if` *expression*, not just the symbol `cl-remove-if`.

Comment: Please reindent your code better. Thx.

Comment: You need to require the library that provides the definition of `cl-remove-if` *before* any code that uses it. Did you do that? You say only that you tried adding the `require` to your init file - it needs to come before any code that uses that function.